# Is it possible to make users subordinate to a user other than root in Linux?

Tags: linux, permissions

I would like to create users that are subordinate to another user in Linux. By this I mean I want the superior user to be related to the subordinate users in two ways:

- The superior user must be able to access all files of subordinate
  users with the same permissions they have
- The superior user must be able to `su` to these subordinate users
  *without entering those users passwords*, similar to how root can `su`
  to any user that has a login shell

Is this possible? If so, how? I know I can manage the first thing with groups, but the second is actually the more important one.

I've been searching around a bit for a solution but I haven't been able to find one. I'm not sure if that means it can't be done/is really obscure or I just don't have the right words to put to it.

Comment: I think PolicyKit should help with the second. I'd look at SELinux though, rather than mucking around with groups.

Comment: Would `sudo` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part – file access – is generally impossible on plain Linux. You can do some things with groups or file ACLs, but there is nothing stopping the file owner from using `chmod` to make their own files private.

There is *no such thing* in Linux as "`X` is subordinate of `root` therefore `root` can access files of `X`".
Instead, root simply has the "override all permission checks" capability (cap_dac_override). That's all.

However, it might be possible to write a LSM that does this – the kind of module that SELinux or SMACK use... **Or** you could simply use `su <subordinate_user>` and read their files that way:

---

The second part is possible by writing custom `sudo` rules or special PAM configuration for `su` (although unfortunately I don't know of any existing PAM modules that would help).

For example, if you wanted to allow user X to run `sudo -u Z -s` (equivalent to `su Z`), the rule would be:

```
X    ALL=(Z) ALL
```

You can also use `%groupname` to specify a Unix group:

```
superiorguy    ALL=(%subordinates) ALL
```

Comment: Changing the sudoers file did it. I can live without the file permissions since I can just allow my user to act as another without a password. Thanks!